# How to return list of object in a stream on flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, rxdart

I have below firestore structure and a method to get user feed from DB.

I need to chain my stream like

1. First all feed ID from User/FeedIDs collection
2. Then for every feedID, get documents for the feed details and return back to list of them.

I could find a way to solve this because `toList()`  is not working or i am doing something wrong.

```
// User Collection
- User
   - RandomDocumentID
      - Feed
         - FeedIDasDocumentID
           - field1
           - field2
             .
             .

// Feed Collection
- Feed
   - RandomDocumentID
      - field1
      - field2
        .
        .

// Method in my repository to get feed for User
Observable<Feed> getCurrentUserFeed(String uid) {
    return Observable(Firestore.instance
          .collection('User')
          .document(uid)
          .collection("FeedIDs")
          .snapshots()
          .expand((snapshots) => snapshots.documents)
          .map((document) => UserFeed.fromMap(document.data))
        )
        .flatMap((userFeed) => Firestore.instance
                               .collection("Feed")
                               .document(userFeed.id)
                               .snapshots()
        )
        .map((document) => Feed.fromMap(document.data));
        // ????
        // I tried to put .toList() and of the stream but it is not working, 
       // i wanna return List<Feed> instead of every single feed object
  }


// in my BLoC
// I had to do that because I could acquire to get streams elements as a list
// 
List<Feed> feedList = List();
FirebaseUser user = await _feedRepository.getFirebaseUser();
_feedRepository.getCurrentUserFeed(user.uid).listen((feed) {
    feedList.add(feed);
    dispatch(UserFeedResultEvent(feedList));
 };
```

If there is any other approach for chaining, it will be really appreciated to share. Thank you

Comment: You're already using `stream.map` which is the answer to chaining computations on the elements in a Stream. I think you're question is better phrased as "Why isn't the Stream from Firestore emitting a done event?" I think that the `snapshots` stream is _intended_ to never end, because it signals when the collection gets updates. You probably want `.snapshots().first()` to get a list of the current documents.

Comment: Thanks, @NateBosch for this advice. Actually, There are two questions. The second one is why "onDone" is not being emitted, as you said it is a continuous stream thats why it is not being emitted. I used ".single()" to fix it.  The second question is, think that user has 5 feeds, and I wanna return a list of feed instead of returning every single feed. Do you have any idea, because ".toList()" . is not working?

Comment: The reason `.toList()` would never complete is because of the missing done event. `.single()` would also not complete I'd expect. `.first` should complete.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the answer to the question. If you write it as the answer, I accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the issue here is that `Firestore` is set up to send updates whenever records change. When you query for `snapshots` it's a Stream that will never send a done event, because new updates could always come in.

Some of the methods on Stream that return a Future will never complete if the stream does not send a done event. These include `.single` and `.toList()`. You are probably looking for `.first` which will complete after the first event is sent through the stream (the current state of the records in the database) and stop listening for changes.